How to Prove $N \subseteq \bigcup_P (X \times Y) \setminus P^*$
Let $N$ be a compact, forward-invariant attracting neighborhood in a dynamical system on $X \times Y$, with an attractor $A = \mathrm{Inv}(N)$. Suppose $P$ ranges over the largest attractors in $N$, and $P^*$ is the repeller associated with $P$.
How can one rigorously prove the decomposition:
$$
N \subseteq \bigcup_{P} \left( (X \times Y) \setminus P^* \right)?
$$
Any hints or references are greatly appreciated! Thank you!
